# MySQL: Retrieve millions of rows from multiple shards at the same time

Tags: mysql, memory-management, scale, mysql-5.7

We have 2 MySQL DBs(both tables in 16 shards) with 100M+ rows and growing/updating. For reporting purposes,

1. I need to fetch all the rows(50M+) on a daily basis, from 1st DB
2. I need to fetch all the rows(50M+) created on that day, from 2nd DB

These rows might update/insertion can happen anytime.

Requirements:

1. Minimum memory utilization(the retrieved data should not be kept in memory, either client or server, before writing into a file)
2. Fetch the data from a midnight DB snapshot.
3. DB snapshot because if the query took 10 mins and data changed in b/w, the data retrieved should be of midnight snapshot(should not fetch the changed/updated data after midnight).
4. There are 16 shards. The dump should happen in all shards at the same time. Else data would be inconsistent.

What is the best way to query the 2 tables with above requirements in mind?

Note: I tried to write a python script with MySQLDB and [this doc](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb-1.2.2/public/MySQLdb.cursors-module.html) mentions that the retrieved data would be kept in either client mem or server mem, which I don't want.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [`SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html) with appropriate transactional isolation.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: I changed the question a little bit and added a few more details about shards. Apart from doing it programmatically, there are only 2 ways - `SELECT INTO OUTFILE` vs `MYSQLDUMP`. What would be the better choice b/w the two with the constraint of the shards?

Comment: It's not _amazingly_ helpful if you ask a question hiding or obfuscating essential details and then add them later.

Comment: It skipped my mind while adding other details and occurred only a little later. Apologies for that. Would like to hear your views on the updated question.